# Fail Safe usage more than half of the total usage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was checking the storage usage for our account and saw more than half is used by Fail Safe

What does it mean if more than %50 of the storage usage is used by Fail Safe?

Comment: Please can you ask a more precise question? Are you asking what failsafe is? Are you asking why it is 50% and, if you are, what would you expect it to be? Also, what is your time travel retention period set to?

Comment: Question is precise enough I believe. Total used storage 270 TB, Database 118 TB, Stage 14 TB, Fail Safe 138 TB. In the 2 lines above there is no question asking what Fail Safe is. I expect to be in less than 10-20 TB. Time travel retention period is 1 day.

Comment: Since you're using a 1 day time travel retention policy, for any table that in your judgement is not worth having the protection of failsafe (usually high-churn pipeline tables), you can define the table as transient. Transient tables have a maximum time travel retention of one day and do not have failsafe. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#transient-tables

Answer (score 1):

Failsafe can be collated data after the time travel is over.
For example if you deleted a number of tables, the Time Travel = 1 day.
Immediately after this, the data is moved to Fail-Safe which can be 0 - 7 days.
In case there are lot of data which is been modified, you will see Fail-safe storage to be high.
In order to get a more perspective view of fail-safe, you need to monitor the data over a period of 7 days and see if this is deleting forever or not.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-failsafe.html

Answer (score 1):

At my list job 1 year ago (when i left) our total disk usage was 180TB 100TB was data (plus that days churn) thus 80Tb was time-travel/failsafe keeping of the churn. I recall we might have bill in the order 6K USD then was in the order of 10% of our monthly compute. So while we did things to improve it we spent more time focusing on compute savings as active tasks.

Now some of the costs where related to tables that had clustering turned on. We made most tables that where generated from primary sources as transient. As we could just rebuild those if “the bad things” happened.

But if you have 120TB of base data it seems you are churning 20TB a day. That seems rather high to me. As an ignore rant outsider. Now that might one days worth of change every thirty minutes. Or you might be rewriting one 20TB once a day. It is hard to judge. For us. Each of the spikes/churn was giving us something as a tradeoff and that saved more in compute cost (more or less). But we where happy. And our storage change was rather slow linear. That again is something that needs to be asked has it changed recently or is you system stable and you are looking to save some dollars.